# Hey , I'm writting a program that reads the radius , x location and y location of two circles with textinputdialog boxes and gets the difference

Tags: java, netbeans

My biggest problem is writing and equation for the difference formula,here's  some of my code ( I haven't formatted it yet.)

```
   boolean doAnother = true;
   
   while (doAnother)
   {
      TextInputDialog inputDialog = new TextInputDialog();
      inputDialog.setHeaderText(null);
      inputDialog.setTitle(null);
      inputDialog.setContentText("Enter the Radius of Circle 1:");
      TextInputDialog inputDialog2 = new TextInputDialog();
      inputDialog2.setHeaderText(null);
      inputDialog2.setTitle(null);
      inputDialog2.setContentText("Enter the X Location of circle 1:");
      TextInputDialog inputDialog3 = new TextInputDialog();
       inputDialog3.setHeaderText(null);
       inputDialog3.setTitle(null);
       inputDialog3.setContentText("Enter the Y Location of circle 1:");
       
      TextInputDialog inputDialog4 = new TextInputDialog();
      inputDialog4.setHeaderText(null);
      inputDialog4.setTitle(null);
      inputDialog4.setContentText("Enter the Radius of Circle 2:");
      TextInputDialog inputDialog5 = new TextInputDialog();
      inputDialog5.setHeaderText(null);
      inputDialog5.setTitle(null);
      inputDialog5.setContentText("Enter the X Location of circle 2:");
      TextInputDialog inputDialog6 = new TextInputDialog();
       inputDialog6.setHeaderText(null);
       inputDialog6.setTitle(null);
       inputDialog6.setContentText("Enter the Y Location of circle 2:");
       
       
       
      Optional<String> numString = inputDialog.showAndWait();
                                   inputDialog2.showAndWait();
                                   inputDialog3.showAndWait();
                                   inputDialog4.showAndWait();
                                   inputDialog5.showAndWait();
                                   inputDialog6.showAndWait();
      
      if (numString.isPresent());
      {
          int num = Integer.parseInt(numString.get());
          
          
          String result = "The Distance is " + 
              ((;));
```

I'm having trouble with coming up with an equation that takes all the values input from the text input boxes

Comment: Do you need an equation or a java function? what are you trying to calculate?
the question is unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the distance between the circles but I do not know to reference the inputs from the text dialog box

Comment: A `TextInputDialog` has no relevance to calculating a distance: Please remove all code not directly related to showing your problem. Is the "distance" you want to calculate the closest distance between two circles? Please clarify.

Comment: *A TextInputDialog has no relevance to calculating a distance* - the OP stated above that `I do not know to reference the inputs from the text dialog box`, Well I can't help because I don't know what a `TextInputDialog` is. That is not a standard class in the JDK.

Comment: A DuckDuckGo search came up with the following: [How to Find the Distance Between Two Points](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Distance-Between-Two-Points).

Comment: the distance between two circles = (the absolute distance between the center of each circle)   -   (the radius of each of the two circles). Now you just have to convert this equation to a function

Comment: @camickr OP's first sentence is *My biggest problem is writing an equation for the difference formula, here's some of my code*, which IMHO means it's a math Q, not a UI Q, so it's not about *how* OP gets the coordinates (ie a `TextInputDialog`), it's about what OP does with them.